# mscode backspace key not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to share this, because it might be useful for you:
I installed VS Code on Ubuntu and connected via remote desktop. Desktop manager is XFWM4.
It seemed to work for a while but suddenly MS Code behaved strangely on some keys: backspace did just nothing, tab switched between windows instead inserting a tab.
After a long time of searching I found that it worked after setting "keyboard.dispatch" to "keyCode" instead of "Code"

However: still some keys do not work as expected - eg. Ctrl+ + zooms in, but Ctrl+ - does not zoom out. And Ctlr+ NumPad0 does not reset the zoom ...